# Round of a negative decimal in C

Tags: c, double

I need to round of decimal numbers to certain precision in my C program. I am facing difficulties in these type of examples

```
x = -0.000000001235
```

which when rounded (using `%.5f`) to five decimals prints `-0.00000`.

How should I remove the negative sign?

Comment: why do you want to remove it?

Comment: what do you expect your output to be ?

Comment: I need to compare it with other element. Though the other end double value is 0, they are not treated as equal elements because of the negative sign.

Comment: @Veltas: That would be too much computation for just a single case.

Comment: @SouravKanta: 0.00000. The negative sign in front of zero makes no sense. I wonder what was the intention!

Comment: @re3el So you can make both values to have `+ve` signs, after that compare the values

Comment: @re3el From your comment,  this is probably a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), describe what exactly you want to achieve in the question.

Comment: If you need to compare them, the easiest solution would be to write in a special case for +/- 0.00000

Comment: @YuHao  I have a result matrix in which there are both positive and negative values. I need to compare it with another matrix. The result matrix after precision is matching with every other respective element except the above case.

Comment: @Veltas: that would be the last choice.

Comment: Displaying the negative sign in this case is at the discretion of the implementation, ISO C does not provide a 'clean' method to choose what happens here, I recommend you just process the output to replace -0.00000 strings with 0.00000.

Comment: can you show how you rounded x using %.5f ? Edit your post by adding that code

Comment: c does not provide a roundiing function(as far as I know).How did you round it ? Or are you just printing it with %.5f .

Comment: The dude appears to be printing it and comparing the printed values somehow. It's not going to be pretty.

Comment: Yes if you are printing the value with %.5f you are doing it wrong. Printing doesn't round your floating number. x will still be -0.000000001235

Comment: @SouravKanta:Yes, I am printing with %.5f. I want my answer to be 0.00000 without a negative sign.

Comment: @user132458: Yeah, I understood that. An answer to help my question would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a perfect example how **not** to do it. Convert two doubles to strings, just to compare them? Oh boy!

Answer (score 2):

If your number is greater than -0.000005 then round the absolute value. You can knock that one on the head with a simple ternary.

If you want to compare numbers to a tolerance of the 5th decimal place then use `fabs(a - b) < 0.00001` as your test for equality. I don't understand why you'd ever want to round numbers explicitly, let alone where the `%.5f` comes in.

Comment: Will this work with doubles/floats? Remember binary floating-points can't accurately represent decimal floating-points in general.

Comment: The "negative zero" is the printing algorithm's choice, it's not related to IEEE's 0.

Comment: Assuming IEEE754, -f can be represented with exactly the same precision as +f. So I don't see a problem.

Comment: Let me clarify: -0.00000 is displayed because it's rounding a negative number. You're worrying about IEEE754 when you should be worrying about ASCII because that's what's being displayed.

Comment: @P45Imminent:  I have a result matrix in which there are both positive and negative values. I need to compare it with another matrix. The result matrix after precision is matching with every other respective element except the above case. I can't use round function as I would be inserting possibilities for many erroneous comparisons.

Comment: Sorry, got the wrong end of the stick. Edited to the correct answer, and invalidated all the comments ;-)

Comment: @P45Imminent: This looks good. But there would be a lot of unnecessary comparisons. Isn't there a better approach?

Comment: +1 might want to show code e.g.


    `printf("%.5f\n", x < 0.0 && x > -0.000005 ? 0.0 : x);`

Comment: re3el printing this result is probably 10000 times slower than doing a floating point comparison.

Comment: @Veltas: "The "negative zero" is the printing algorithm's choice, it's not related to IEEE's 0": You are right for the example, but IEEE actually **has** `-0.0`. A rounding algorithm might very well produce this result. However, the standard requires both zeroes to compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good methods of dealing with your problem.

You could add some basic comparison code to handle the range that causes the problem:

```
printf("%.5f ", -0.000005 < x && x < 0.0 ? 0.0 : x);
```

Or you could interpret your output to replace lines containing `-0.00000` with `0.00000`.

However you have expressed concerns with performance, which suggests you are going the wrong way about solving your problem.

If printing these values is an intermediate step in an expensive calculation, then this is definitely a bad idea, you should write your own rounding function.

If this is just the end of the calculation, then these extra comparisons or replacements will have an unnoticeable effect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

To round a FP to 5 places and not incur a negative `-0.00000`

1. Accept the most rounded values will not be *exact*, but will be the closest representable number to the rounded math result.
2. *Do not* use a cast/conversion to an integer type due to loss of range.
3. -0.0 --> +0.0

Sample solution:

```
#include <math.h>
double round_to_5_places(double x) {
  // Only need to round finite numbers, leave infinity and not-a-numbers alone 
  if (isfinite(x)) {
    // break x into integral and fractional parts
    double ipart;
    double fpart = modf(x, &ipart);
    // Only need to round if a fractional part exist.
    // This test prevents the below `100000.0 * fpart` from overflowing.
    if (fpart) {
      // Use rint(), round(), nearbyint(), etc. depending on rounding detail needs
      x = ipart + nearbyint(100000.0 * fpart)/100000.0;
    }
    x += 0.0; // Only changes -0.0 to 0.0
  }
  return x;
}
```

Detail: some half way-cases near `x == N.000005` will round the wrong way due to `100000.0 * fpart` itself forming a rounded product before the `nearbyint()` call.  See [Double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding). The usual solution involves performing higher precision multiplication.